# Mounting private GitHub repository into a pod's volume

Tags: github, docker, volume, kubernetes

Has anyone mounted a private GitHub repository into a kubernetes pod volume?

What is the best way to achieve this?
I thought of two possible ways:

1. Using user / password in HTTPS repository URL
2. Using private SSH key on the machine

I like the second better, but I couldn't figure which user is pulling the repository to puts the appropriate SSH configuration for it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub allows cloning repositories using an OAuth token in https URLs as such:

`$ git clone https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/owner/repo.git`

see
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/

Comment: Is kubernetes reading the $GH_TOKEN environment variable on pod definition?